# Is it safe to alias cp -R to cp?

Tags: bash, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

When I copy something, I always forget the `-R`, then I have go all the way back to add it right after `cp`.
I want to add this to bash config files.

`alias cp="cp -R"`

I have not seen anything bad happen. Is it safe to do this?

Comment: I would consider `-a` instead. It's the same as `cp -R -d --preserve=all`. However, I can't comment on whether either option could have surprising bad effects

Comment: I would use `alias cpr="cp -R"` so you don't change behavior of `cp` for install scripts, makefiles, etc.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth aliases only work in the shell session in which they have been defined. As makefiles and scripts run in their own session, there is no risk of aliases changing their behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that would cause unexpected behavior with the `-R` flag is that it doesn't work with wildcards.

What I mean is... for example you want to copy all mp3 Files in a directory and every subdirectory with: `cp -R /path/*.mp3`. Although `-R` is given it will not copy mp3s in the subdirectories of `path` - if there are any.

Comment: Wow you are right. I just tested it. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use aliases for changing the behaviour of normal commands. When you are in a different shell / another computer, the alias will be missing. When a friend wants to help you, he will not know what you did.
Once I had an `alias rm="rm -i"` and I performed `rm *`, while I just had changed shell with a `su`. 
And sometimes you want to use cp without the -R option, will you remember to use `/bin/cp` in these cases (copy all files in the current dir to another location, but do not cp the subdirs)?

Comment: Thanks. I will use it with caution. :)